# cURL 7.15.5 and PayPal payment

Tags: php, paypal

I have hosting with 7.15.5 curl version that can't be updated right now.
I am trying to connect to PayPal API but following error emerges:

> 14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure

Is 7.15.5 curl a dead end or can is there some solution to that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yet another Paypal Curl / SSL v3 Handshake Error - SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003430/yet-another-paypal-curl-ssl-v3-handshake-error-ssl23-get-server-hellosslv3/35106129) I am afraid you'll need to upgrade PHP cURL and OpenSSL

Comment: When exactly PayPal drop support for lower versions of curl?

Comment: @Krystus: Paypal did not drop support for old curl versions but for older versions of TLS. And old curl versions just happen to use old OpenSSL versions which do not support the newer TLS protocol versions. And it looks like they only disabled this for www.sandbox.paypal.com, possible in preparaton for PCI 3.1 compliance where TLS 1.0 is not allowed anymore.